# Treat number as Zero in mysql query

Tags: mysql

If have rows table like this

```
    id      content
    1       this five lenght is 12345
    2       this five lenght is 23456
    3       this six lenght is 234567
    4       this six lenght is 238567
```

Then when I want to select and group by content, it will result

```
    SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY content

    1       this five lenght is 00000
    3       this six lenght is 000000
```

Is there a way to achieve this, that can replace number with zero in mysql query?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: we always update things I think we have new version. wait I will check

Comment: | innodb_version          | 5.7.23                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1           |
| version                 | 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | Linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Replace numbers with zero and then group them.

Example for replacement:

```
Select REGEXP_REPLACE('Stackoverflow 2456','[0-9]','0')
Stackoverflow 0000
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db93de9c1c965090f46b4dbb1f48a63e

In your case:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(CONTENT, '[0-9]','0') FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY REGEXP_REPLACE(CONTENT, '[0-9]','0')
```

Be careful tho this will probably do a full TABLE scan, so it will be really slow on large tables.

Comment: The second example will (hopefully) fail.

Comment: function REGEXP_REPLACE doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function - it'll work on mysql 8+ version

```
SELECT id, REGEXP_REPLACE (content,'[0-9]', '0') as content
FROM tablename GROUP BY REGEXP_REPLACE (content,'[0-9]', '0')
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will check first. I will be back if it works. Thanks

Comment: function REGEXP_REPLACE doesnt exist

Comment: @klaudia, what is your mysql  version?

Comment: | innodb_version | 5.7.23 | | protocol_version | 10 | | slave_type_conversions | | | tls_version | TLSv1,TLSv1.1 | | version | 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 | | version_comment | (Ubuntu) | | version_compile_machine | x86_64 | | version_compile_os | Linux